# Get string in between two words | last occurance

Tags: regex

So, I have been searching around and could find many answers but, they don't answer my questions. This is the code I use to get the strings between `"duration":` and `,` it works fine but, it gets every occurrence, I want to get only the last occurrence.  [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/409)

```
(?<=\"duration":)(.*?)(?=\,)
```

gets:

> {"duration": **5.016**, "duration": **5.016**, "duration": **5.016**,
>   "duration": **125**,}

and I would like to get.

> {"duration": 5.016, "duration": 5.016, "duration": 5.016, "duration":
>   **125**,}

This is not just for JSON

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Comment: The [tag:regex] tag alone is not sufficient, please add the tag of the environment you use regular expressions in so you can get an answer that actually fixes your problem instead of giving you a hack that may or may not work. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, the sample provided is not valid JSON.

Comment: I never said I wanted to do it for only JSON, I want to do it for everything.

Comment: That's is just a example.

Comment: OP wrote a clear problem, showed attempted code, mentioned clearly it is not JSON, got downvoted without reason. And I tried answering with demo and explanation got downvoted without any apparent reason :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use lookahead regex like this:

```
(?<="duration": )[^,]+(?!.*"duration")
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/410)

- `[^,]+` matches 1 or more of any character that is not comma,
- `(?!.*"duration")` is a negative lookahead that asserts we have no occurrence of `"duration"` ahead of the current position.

Comment: Why do people always downvote when they don't like something? anyways, thanks for your answer.